# Pressure exerted by gas on the wall of a container

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, kinetic-theory

The pressure exerted by gas on the wall of container is given by $P= (1/3)*ρ*v²$, $v$ is r.m.s velocity, $ρ$ is density of the gas while deriving this, there is an assumption made that the components of the velocity are same in every direction (ie) $Vx= Vy= Vz$ (x component of velocity is same as y and z component of velocity) why is that?, this assumption is too specific to be considered as a general equation

Comment: Cite your reference

Comment: How do the molecules know what direction they should travel?

Comment: The direction of propogation of molecules on average can be considered equal under the condition of statistical isotropy, or $\left<v_x^2\right> = \left<v_y^2\right> = \left<v_z^2\right>$.

Answer (score 2):

That assumption is not too general to be considered for the general equation. In fact, it follows from the assumption that the distribution of velocities within the gas is rotationally symmetric. This is a very safe assumption and in fact you need to make it in order to obtain a consistent pressure. For example, if the gas mostly traveled horizontally the pressure would be higher on the side walls than the top or bottom ones, and a scalar pressure wouldn't make sense any more (in contrast, in a solid, there are lots of things that can break rotational symmetry and the scalar pressure gives way to the tensor stress).

This rotational symmetry follows from the fact that gas molecules are mostly interacting with each other. These molecules are themselves roughly spherically symmetric on average basically because space is rotationally symmetric. What, then, could break the spherical symmetry?

One possible answer is the irregular walls of the container, but under typical conditions the mean free path of the gas molecules is much smaller than the size of their container, so this effect is typically negligible. Similarly, a field like gravity can only hold a gas molecule within tens of kilometers of the surface, so it's pretty negligible within a typical, much-smaller container.